# Looking for correct object notation to represent JSON-style data in C#

Tags: c#, json, notation

I'm used to making web apps using JSON but now I have to develop in C# and I'm running into difficulty choosing the correct object notation as I have little formal training.

Basically I want to re-create the following JSON in C#:

```
{
    "10003": {
        "computer": 25,
        "desk": 23,
        "chair": 7,
        "score": 44
    },
    "10004": {
        "computer": 35,
        "desk": 23,
        "chair": 7,
        "score": 77
    },
    etc...
}
```

So that I can access or change any value quickly by doing something like:

```
myObjectName["10003"]["score"] = 23
```

I also need to rank the order of the high level keys ('10003', '10004, etc.') based on the value of 'score' they have inside them.

I've been considering some combination of a Dictionary of Lists of KeyValuePairs but I'm looking for the simplest/correct method of notation in this instance?

EDIT: I'm not trying to convert JSON. I don't have any JSON. I was just showing how I would do it with JSON. I'm looking for a native C# method, unless everyone in C# is just using JSON?

Comment: I assume you are familiar with NewtonSoft.json lib? you can define a class in your code with these fields, and serialize and deserialize using them. Or are you asking for some other approach?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a native approach without using JSON at all

Comment: @mjwills How easy is it to sort the nested dictionaries by one of the inner dictionary's int properties??

Comment: If you look at the JSON equivalent I have posted in the question, I want to sort the dictionaries by the value of their 'score' key. Is that possible?

Comment: @mjwills If you elaborate on how to use OrderBy on retrieval and submit it as an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to consider is to store it in a `Dictionary` of `Dictionary` and then `OrderBy` as needed:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bob = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

    bob["10003"] = new Dictionary<string, int> {
        { "computer", 25 },
        { "desk", 23 },
        { "chair", 7 },
        { "score", 44} };
    bob["10004"] = new Dictionary<string, int> {
        { "computer", 35 },
        { "desk", 23 },
        { "chair", 7 },
        { "score", 77} };
    bob["10005"] = new Dictionary<string, int> {
        { "computer", 85 },
        { "desk", 23 },
        { "chair", 7 },
        { "score", 10} };

    var ordered = bob.OrderBy(z => z.Value["score"]).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(ordered.First().Value["computer"]); // 85 since 10 is the lowest score
    Console.WriteLine(ordered.Last().Value["computer"]); // 35 since 77 is the highest score

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I was also able to sort the dictionary using myDict = myDict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value["score"]).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

Comment: No, don't do `ToDictionary` @AzzyDude. `Dictionary` instances are explicitly **not** guaranteed to be ordered. It may work **today** but not **forever** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks . `The order in which the items are returned is undefined.` `ToList` will be fine since it **will** maintain order.

Comment: Also if **every entity** has the **same** fields (`computer`, `chair` etc) then consider adding a new `MyEntry` class with all of the appropriate fields in it (`computer`, `chair` etc) to avoid the need for the inner `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Convert it into dataset as:

```
DataSet myDataSet= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonstring);
```

And then change data like:

```
myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["10003"]["score"]=23;
```

Comment: I should clarify I don't already have a JSON string I am trying to convert. That was just to give an indicator of how I would do it in JSON. I am reading the data from an SQL database and can organize it any way I want. Is there not a native C# approach to store the data and achieve the same results?